Optimal Methods for Converting SASS to SCSS
The issue lies in efficiently transforming .sass to .scss.
Although sass-convert is an outdated npm library, it was the only one I found that fulfilled my requirements. To use it, first install Ruby, then install RubyGems. Next, use RubyGems to install Sass via command gem install sass. Now that sass is installed, sass-convert is included as part of the package. To convert all files, run command sass-convert -R ./ -F sass -T scss. While the library might encounter some conversion issues, it handles most cases. If sass-convert fails, you can manually convert files using this converter. However, this site occasionally struggles with commented lines, so removing them usually resolves the issue.
The primary reason for transitioning from Sass to SCSS is that SCSS uses brackets instead of spaces for scoping, which prevents formatting errors when using tools like Prettier.
Are there alternative efficient methods or libraries available for converting SASS to SCSS?

Please note that resource requests (including libraries or tools) are off-topic on Stack Overflow.
